# How would I make a group vertices all the same distance from an Axis line?

Tags: vertices

Essentially I want to turn the selected portion into a cylinder (but keep the z value for each vertex).
[image]
I don't even know if this is possible. Another possible way to do this ig would somehow change to polar coordinated and scale to 0 along the r coordinate, but idk how to do that.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here.  Could you explain more?

Comment: I want to turn all of the selected vertices into a cylinder by moving them along the xy plane.

Comment: The accepted answer is fine to solve your issue.

You should also check out the LoopTools add-on, free and included w/ blender installer IIRC.  You can select a loop of edges, right-click, select Loop Tools, and click 'Circle.'  LoopTools will try to create a circle from the verts/edges you selected.  

Doesn't always work perfectly, but it's a great modeling tool to use in the midst of edit mode.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, I think my topology was just bad so it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *Cast* modifier, set to 'Cylinder', with a *Factor* of 1, aimed at a vertex-group made of the selection you show, should do the job.

- The Cylinder will be formed around the local Z axis of your object, or that of a control-object you allocate in the modifier.
- It will be formed by pushing vertices *outward* toward the given radius. If the minimum is too large, the modifier may have to be applied, and the vertices scaled back to the desired final size.
- The vertex Z-coordinates, in the cylinder's space, are not affected.

These tubes have been solidified for illustration.

[image]

Settings:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the modifier settings? I'm a bit confused

Comment: I got it! Thank you

Comment: @MaxGordon  Great! The edit may still help others out.